# Ember.js order hasMany children

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a item model and each item can have many items.  This can be many levels deep.

I have this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rmossuk/xmcBf/3/

how do I change this to be able to have multiple levels of items and also how do I loop down each level to display them ?

I also need be able to order each items children and store that order to persist to server.

please can anyone show me how you can do this ?

**UPDATE:**

I have now managed to implement the Items can be many levels deep bit of this problem see here http://jsfiddle.net/rmossuk/fBmmS/3/

But i need a way to state the order of each items children and to display them in that order.   At the moment it just displays the children items from the itemIds array but this is only used for association purposes and i cant change this to re-order can i ??

Anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks a lot
rick

Comment: If you have resolved this, do you mind posting the solution.

Comment: i have not resolved it yet!  still trying !    Hope someone can help me soon.

Comment: I have seen that Ember.ArrayController has a sortProperties but cant seem to work out how to add an ArrayController for each item to store each items children order.   Hope someone can help soon

Comment: Here I am! Hope I will help... :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the views, use a `sortedItems` computed property, defined as follow:.

**JS**

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  index: DS.attr('number'),
  items: DS.hasMany('App.Item', {key: 'itemIds'} ),
  item: DS.belongsTo('App.Item'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('App.Product'),

  sortedItems: function () {
    var items = this.get('items').toArray();
    return items.sort(function (lhs, rhs) {
      return lhs.get('index') - rhs.get('index');
    });
  }.property('items.@each.isLoaded')
});
```

See a full working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/K286Q/3/

---

***EDIT***

According to your request, here is another solution, keeping the sorted ids inside the parent (to minimize updates & indexes management): http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/K286Q/12/

**JS**

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  items: DS.hasMany('App.Item', {key: 'itemIds'} ),
  sortedIds: DS.attr('string', { key: 'sortedIds' }),
  item: DS.belongsTo('App.Item'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('App.Product'),

  sortedChildren: function () {
    if (!this.get('isLoaded')) {
      return [];
    }
    var sortedIds = this.get('sortedIds').split(','),
        items = this.get('items').toArray();
    return sortedIds.map(function (id) {
      if (id === '') {
        return null;
      }
      return items.find(function (item) {
          return item.get('id') == id;
      });
    }).filter(function(item) {
      return !!item;
    });
  }.property('isLoaded', 'sortedIds', 'items.@each.isLoaded')
});
```

A little bit more complicated, nevertheless...

Comment: Thanks mike for the answer have been trying sort this for a few days!!      Is there a way i can do this by storing the order on the parent without having to store an index on each item ?    trying to do this because if i change the order or an item with this solution i then have to change all index on each child item and persist all these changes to server.  Where as if i can just store the actual order of the children on the parent, when i change any of its childrens order i only have to save and persist the parent.     Hope this makes sense??   any ideas ??    thanks a lot

Comment: Hey Mike thats amazing, thanks a lot i really appreciate it.   I owe you one!

Comment: For me the use of .toArray() was really interesting. No doc tells how to get hasMany relations back intro a format you can actually work with. Thank you & +1