# Ember: access has many relationship array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have, say:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

In some code, I retrieve the `post` and I want to loop on its comments:

```
var comment;
var post = store.all('post').content[0];
for (var i=0; i<post.get('comments').length; i++) { // length attributes exists
  // comment is undefined
  comment = post.get('comments')[i]; // also tried post.get('comments').get(i);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was a `toArray()` method, found thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767446/ember-js-order-hasmany-children), though I never found it in the doc:

```
var comment;
var post = store.all('post').content[0];
var comments = post.get('comments').toArray();
for (var i=0; i<comments.length; i++) { // length attributes exists
  comment = comments[i];
}
```